# R Shiny: Perform a series of functions on reactive input

Tags: r, shiny

I want to perform a series of tasks on a data.frame that will be loaded by the user via actionButton. Here is an example where I want to remove rows with NAs in the third column of the data.frame selected by the user. I get the error:

> "Warning: Error in observeEventHandler: object 'df' not found
>
> Stack trace (innermost first):
>
> > 65: observeEventHandler [(file location).R#56]"

Why doesn't observeEvent recognize the variable f?

**Server.R**

```
library(shiny)

 shinyServer <- function(input, output) {
    filedata <- reactive({
        infile <- input$Samples
        if (is.null(infile)) {
            # User has not uploaded a file yet
            return(NULL)
        }
        df <- read.table(infile$datapath,sep="\t",skip =0, header = TRUE,na.strings = "NA",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
        })

    observeEvent(input$Click, {
            selectA <- df[complete.cases(f[,3]),]
    }
}
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

 shinyUI( <- fluidPage(
    tabPanel("Inputs",
         wellPanel(fileInput(inputId = "Samples", label = "Import File"), 
                   actionButton(inputId = "Click", label = "Samples")),
         h2('Results'),
         dataTableOutput("Results")))
```

Comment: `df` is a variable local to the `filedata` reactive object. What are you tying to do here? Where do you want this reduced set of rows to ultimately go? It seems you haven't quite learned the proper reactive data model that Shiny uses. There are useful introductions on the [Shiny developer conference page](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/)

Comment: Ultimately I want to run a function on a file uploaded by the user and display the results in tables, plots, spatially, etc. I have the function working properly as a script but I want to have it run as part of a Shiny interface.

Comment: When you write R scripts you may write functions but it's basically declarative code. Shiny uses a reactive paradigm. The code will look very different. I suggest you start with a basic tutorial or the videos I linked to. There really isn't a clear question here that's answerable in the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I didn't do a good job of articulating my question. Here is the answer that I was looking for.

**Server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer <- function(input, output) {
    filedata <- reactive({
     infile <- input$Samples
     if (is.null(infile)) {
        # User has not uploaded a file yet
        return(NULL)
    }
    read.table(infile$datapath,sep="\t",skip =0, header = TRUE,na.strings = "NA",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    })

    observeEvent(input$Click, {
     df <- filedata()
     selectA <- df[complete.cases(df[,3]),]
    }
}
```